# Change the parent of a WPF element after a rotation (setting new coordinates issue)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rotation, position

I need to change the parent of elements. (for group/ungroup shapes) 
But I cant set the new position for an element if it has a rotation.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581837/wpf-getting-new-coordinates-after-a-rotation) ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241740/getting-new-position-of-a-line-after-rotation) , [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ea1c45f5-dc17-4c3d-b1dd-e8b77af73c89/get-actual-image-position-after-rotation-in-a-canvas?forum=wpf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286393/wpf-rotate-rectangle-and-place-it-in-canvas) pages and many other ways, but none worked correctly.

Please see [my sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7xJ3vpXXdvQYjlFempoY2RsRVU/view?usp=sharing) and the following image:

[image]

The parent of `Rect1` is `ChildCanvas1` and The parent of `Rect2` is `ChildCanvas2`, I want to move the `Rect1` and `Rect2` to the `MainCanvas`. (and remove the `ChildCanvas` and `ChildCanvas2`)

I don't have any problem to do that for the `Rect1` because it has not any rotation. 
But the `Rect2` has a rotation (-20 degree) and I cant set the new coordinates for it correctly.

Please see this image:

[image]

How to change the parent of an element after a rotation and setting new coordinates correctly?

**UPDATE:**

Note I need a general way (for the group/ungroup elements in a big app that each element (maybe) has `TranslateTransform` and `SkewTransform` and `RotateTransform` and `ScaleTransform`)

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas">
    <Canvas x:Name="ChildCanvas1" Width="500" Height="250" Background="Bisque" Canvas.Top="54">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="100"/>
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas Name="ChildCanvas2" Width="500" Height="250" Background="Bisque" Canvas.Left="516" Canvas.Top="54">
        <Rectangle Name="Rect2" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="100">
              <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="-40"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-20"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
    <Button Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click" Content="Move Rect1 to MainCanvas and Remove ChildCanvas1" Width="356" Height="30" Canvas.Left="59" Canvas.Top="310"/>
    <Button Name="btn2"  Click="btn2_Click" Content="Move Rect2 to MainCanvas and Remove ChildCanvas2" Width="350" Height="30" Canvas.Left="590" Canvas.Top="310"/>
```

C# code :

```
GeneralTransform transform = Rect2.TransformToVisual(MainCanvas);
Rect rect = transform.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, Rect2.Width, Rect2.Height));
double ChildCanvas2Left = Canvas.GetLeft(ChildCanvas2);
double ChildCanvas2Top = Canvas.GetLeft(ChildCanvas2);
ChildCanvas2.Children.Remove(Rect2);
MainCanvas.Children.Add(Rect2);
Canvas.SetLeft(Rect2, rect.Left);
Canvas.SetTop(Rect2, rect.Top);
MainCanvas.Children.Remove(ChildCanvas2);
```

Comment: Can you show your XAML code?

Comment: @S.Akbari , Please download my sample project.

Comment: OK. Check my answer. Also please update your question and post the XAML and c# code instead of attachment to your project so that it will be reproducible to future visitors.

Comment: @S.Akbari  ,OK ,Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recalculate the `Rect2` after moving the `Rect2` to the `MainCanvas`. Like this:

```
Canvas.SetTop(Rect2, Canvas.GetTop(Rect2) + Canvas.GetTop(ChildCanvas2));
```

The complete code:

```
private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    GeneralTransform transform = Rect2.TransformToVisual(MainCanvas);
    Rect rect = transform.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, Rect2.Width, Rect2.Height));
    ChildCanvas2.Children.Remove(Rect2);
    MainCanvas.Children.Remove(ChildCanvas2);
    Canvas.SetLeft(Rect2, rect.Left);
    Canvas.SetTop(Rect2, Canvas.GetTop(Rect2) + Canvas.GetTop(ChildCanvas2));
    MainCanvas.Children.Add(Rect2);      
}
```

However `Rect2.TransformToVisual` and `transform.TransformBounds` are not necessary in your case and you can do it more cleaner and easier without them and get same result. Like this:

```
ChildCanvas2.Children.Remove(Rect2);
MainCanvas.Children.Remove(ChildCanvas2);
Canvas.SetLeft(Rect2, Canvas.GetLeft(Rect2) + Canvas.GetLeft(ChildCanvas2));
Canvas.SetTop(Rect2, Canvas.GetTop(Rect2) + Canvas.GetTop(ChildCanvas2));
MainCanvas.Children.Add(Rect2);
```

**EDIT**: A general way:

```
ChildCanvas2.Children.Remove(Rect2);
MainCanvas.Children.Remove(ChildCanvas2);
Canvas.SetLeft(Rect2, Canvas.GetLeft(Rect2) + Canvas.GetLeft(ChildCanvas2));
Canvas.SetTop(Rect2, Canvas.GetTop(Rect2) + Canvas.GetTop(ChildCanvas2));
Canvas.SetRight(Rect2, Canvas.GetRight(Rect2) + Canvas.GetRight(ChildCanvas2));
Canvas.SetBottom(Rect2, Canvas.GetBottom(Rect2) + Canvas.GetBottom(ChildCanvas2));
MainCanvas.Children.Add(Rect2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have changed `RenderTransform` to `LayoutTransform` of `Rect2`:

```
<Rectangle Name="Rect2" Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="100">
       <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
           <RotateTransform Angle="-20"/>
       </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Now `Rect2` looks like below:

[image]

When I press the second button I see this result:

[image]

So, `Rect2` stays at the original position.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to do it using RenderTransform .(not LayoutTransform)